# delete image and thumbnail image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, crud, thumbnails

i try to delete some image file in laravel project. i follow tutorial on website, and its work, but tutorial only deleted image based name in column image. the thumbnail on folder image didnt deleted. how to delete image also the thumbnail image? pls help.
this is the store function.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destination = public_path() . '/galeri/';
            $successUploaded = $request->file('image')->move($destination, $file->getClientOriginalName());
            
            if($successUploaded)
            {
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$extension}", "_thumb.{$extension}", $image);

                Image::make($destination . '/' . $image)
                ->resize(250, 170)
                ->save($destination . '/' . $thumbnail);
            }
            $photo->image = $image;
        }
        $photo->save();
```

and this the destroy function

```
$photo = Photo::where('id', $id)->first();
        File::delete('galeri/'.$photo->image);
        if($photo){
            $photo->delete();
        }
```

Comment: You know the thumbnail names as well. It is `originalImageName_thumb.originalExtension` . use that information to delete that file as well. Alternatively you can store thumbnail name in database as well, for example in a column called `thumbnail`. Then use the same logic to delete `$photo->thumbnail`

Answer (score 0):

Delete a single file

```
 File::delete($filename);
```

Delete multiple files

```
File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);
```

Delete an array of files

```
$files = array($file1, $file2);
File::delete($files);
```